# An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting the above error in this code`

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string veturaid = Request.QueryString["VetID"].ToString();
        int vetuid = int.Parse(veturaid);

       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-SUV91Q2\\AGONAJREDINI;Initial Catalog=VeturaOnline;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true ");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select PerdID from Perdoruesit where Username='" + btnuser.Text + "'", con);
        
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string str = "";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            str = (reader["PerdID"].ToString());
            id = int.Parse(str);
        }
        

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Veturat where VetID='" + vetuid + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        string modeli = "";
        
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                modeli = (reader["Modeli"].ToString());

            }
        reader1.Close();`
```

I'm getting the error at this line  `modeli = (reader["Modeli"].ToString());`
Any idea why it is happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `reader1["Modeli"]` instead of `reader["Modeli"]`?

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I've spent hours trying to fix this and it was a typo. Thank you very much @Karan